# Pattern works with / but it does not work when used in filter function()

Tags: regular-expression, filter

I want to extract the the substring `Python 3.11` from the strings like `Python 3.11.2.release0` (i.e. I want to extract `Python`  followed by the first two digits separated by a `.`). Such longer strings often come from system output of  `python --version`.
Hence, my attempt is the following:

```
var myvar = system('python --version') -> filter("v:val =~ 'Python\ \d\+.\d\+'")
```

but it always result in an empty `myvar`.

Interestingly, if I have a buffer that contains the string `Python 3.11.2.release0` and  I type `/Python\ \d\+.\d\+` the pattern `Python 3.11` is correctly highlighted (I have `incsearch` set).

I am interested in Vim9.

EDIT: the utilisation of `systemlist` instead of `system` produce the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A space is not allowed between `->` and the name of the function. Fixed:

   ```
   var myvar = system('python --version')->filter("v:val =~ 'Python\ \d\+.\d\+'")
   ```
2. Whether you are interested in vim9script or not is irrelevant, here, as the functions work the same. This variant of your snippet makes that pointless requirement disappear:

   ```
   :echo system('python --version')->filter("v:val =~ 'Python\ \d\+.\d\+'")
   ```
3. `:help filter()` is not at all adapted to what you are trying to do. Use `:help matchstr()` instead:

   ```
   :echo system('python --version')->matchstr('Python\ \d\+\.\d\+')
   ```

Comment: Auch! `matchstr()` !!!